# Primality of a number

Tags: algorithm, primes, primality-test

It's known that to check whether a number 'n' is prime or not we just need to check whether it has a factor less than the square root of n.

My question is isn't it is sufficient to check for all primes less than the square root of n.

Comment: Yes, if you happen to know the primes.

Comment: Less than or equal to... otherwise you'll think eg. 4 and 9 are primes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3):

Every integer *n* greater than 1 either is prime itself or is the product of prime numbers ([Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)). Thus if *n* isn't a prime itself it must be divisible by at least two primes. At least one of these must be less than **or equal to** √*n* (otherwise their product would be greater than *n*), so it is sufficient to check for all the primes less than **or equal to** √*n*.

Answer (score 0):

We can argue like this:

Let the number to check be `n`. Let there be a number `k <= sqrt(n)` which divides `n`. Now, we can write `k` as follows:

```
k = (p_1^a_1)(p_2^a_2)...(p_x^a_x)
```

where `p_1, p_2, ..., p_x` are prime number less than or equal to `k` and `a_1, a_2, ..., a_x >= 1`. Now, since `k` divides `n`, and since we know that `p_1, p_2, ..., p_x` divides `k`, by transitivity, we can deduce that `p_1, p_2, ..., p_x` divides `n`. Thus, to prove that `n` is  non-prime, it is sufficient to check if any of the prime numbers `<= sqrt(n)` divides `n` or not.

Comment: Upvoted, but your argument can be simpler -- k has at least one prime factor p, and p | k | n, so p divides n. [You also need to check prime numbers <= sqrt(n) rather than < sqrt(n) to catch the cases when n is the square of a prime].

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks for pointing out the missing `equals` in last argument. And I agree that my argument is a bit verbose but I think the crust of both the argument (yours and mine) is same. Shall I trim down my answer?

Comment: Yes, I agree it's the same idea. I think it'd make a better answer if you edited it down since that'd make the idea easier to see. But up to you if you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, what you are saying is absolutely correct**.

You just need to check for all the primes less than equal to `squareRoot(n)`, but the point is you don't know whether the number is prime or not. So, you traverse till `squareRoot(n)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is only need to check the factor less sqrt(n). But this algorithm is a little bit slow. I have another better algorithm called Miller_Rabin_primality [My previous project code](https://github.com/jeremykid/Algorithm_project/blob/master/Miller_Rabin_primality_test.py)
[Source code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)

Here is the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)